# Telling svn (tortoise) that a certain branch has already been merged

Tags: svn, merge

In a project I'm working on, we have a problem with branching/merging.

To simplify, we have a branch A (owned by our client) and a branch B (owned by us), and we periodically syncronize A with B so all new changes made at B are brought to A when the client says so (when client certifies that code at branch B have been properly tested, execution works properly, etc).

The problem is that sometimes merging is done in an incorrect way so SVN doesn't know which commits has been already merged and which doesn't. The changes and the ways conflicts have been solved are correct, functionally spoken, but SVN doesn't know that. So if you try to merge all revisions from two branches already merged, all previously solved conflicts appear again. If I specify the option "include merged revisions", in SVN log, some "merging commits" doesn't unfold to show all the commits that are included in such merges. That's how I know that this metadata has been lost.

I think the problem is that sometimes some people request the merge in a local copy, and the conflicts are manually solved in another local copy so after committing from such copy the SVN server doesn't receive the metadata that was generated when you requested the merge in the first place.

So you cannot just "synchronize branches" from B to A, because the situation is unmaintenable. The only option left is to manually specify the range of revisions to merge, but we don't want to do this anymore.

So, how can we say to SVN, "hey, all of the changes from B have already been merged, and the conflicts have been solved in A, despite what you think"?

**NOTE:** We use Tortoise SVN.

Comment: You should specify the version of your SVN client and server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the third page of the merge wizard there is a checkbox "Only record the merge (block revisions from getting merged)". Check it. The result would be to just write revisions to `svn:mergeinfo` property.